# Is there anything like xvfb or xnest for Windows?

Tags: windows, user-interface, testing

On projects with end-to-end tests that drive the GUI, it is awkward to run the tests on a developer workstation because the GUI automation driver interferes with the desktop. It moves the mouse, steals focus away from apps we want to use, and can start typing text into the wrong application if we switch to another app during a test run.

On Linux we've solved this by running the application under test on a virtual X server (xvfb or xnest).  With xnest we can watch the tests running but still use the real desktop without interference.

Is there anything equivalent for Windows?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found a freeware program called "RunProcess.exe" written by Frank P. Westlake that can run a process bound to the desktop of a non-interactive (e.g. off-screen) WindowStation.  However, there is no source.

Therefore I've implemented my own version (simpler than Frank Westlake's) with Java and JNA. It's in the [Window Licker](https://github.com/petercoulton/windowlicker) repository in the tools module. The class is called `com.objogate.wl.win32.RunOnDesktop`.  At some point I may port it to C and make it a normal command-line .exe, or maybe turn it into an Ant task for running tests off-screen.

Comment: how about the keyboard & mouse issues of doing it off the screen @Nat ?

Comment: Link for Window licker is broken

Answer (score 8):

You can use "[Desktops](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/cc817881.aspx)" application from SysInternals package. Run UI tests on one desktop and work on another.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think that will work.  What I want is to spawn a process from the IDE (running on my main desktop) and for that process' windows to appear on an off-screen desktop.  That's not the way that "Desktops" appears to work.

Comment: I had this same issue and this solution worked for me. You can spawn your process directly from the "hidden" desktop and keep it working there and switch back to your main desktop, thanks Yauheni Sivukha for this solution

Comment: Does this really solve the original question where one issue was that the automation driver moves the mouse ? Then there would have to be separate mouse pointers/input on the different desktops.

Comment: This is good for visual needs.
But it does not have a separate sound source and the sounds are all combined and played at the same time!

Answer (score -1):

I just tried the multiple desktop method on my Windows 10 machine.  I'm running Selenium Javascript tests.  I started the tests on another desktop and waited for it to open the browser, then switched back to my main desktop.  But at the same point where the Chrome browser would become the active window, now it actually forced me back to that desktop :-(

I think I'll try RunProcess.exe, or Nat's solution.

Comment: I just tried the Sysinternals Desktops tool https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/cc817881.aspx and it works OK for me.  When I launched a test on that other desktop there was no interaction with my original desktop :-)