# Is there any way to install xvbf for windows?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium-webdriver, capybara, headless

Actually i need to run `Selenium webdriver` using `Firefox profile` for `headless testing`. But I am unable to find `Xvbf` support for `Windows`. Is there any alternate way to achieve this. I would be very thankful if someone guide me any workaround.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/969837/1047207 - This may help you

Comment: not useful in my case, i have seen this link already.