# Mink and Behat: Is there a way to launch selenium (Chrome) in background?

Tags: behat, mink

When running tests, I would like not to be bothered by Chrome popping-up every time Behat launches a scenario needing Chrome.

I know there is a `maximizeWindow()` method for `session` objects, but nothing like "minimize".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nowadays, you can set Chrome to run in headless mode like so (`behat.yml`):

```
default:
    extensions:
        Behat\MinkExtension:
            javascript_session: browser
            sessions:
                browser:
                    selenium2:
                        browser: chrome
                        capabilities:
                            chrome:
                                switches:
                                    - "--headless"
```

Comment: I tried your solution at last, working fine ! BUT I had to update both selenium server and chrome driver.

Answer (score 1):

You could run Chrome with a virtual framebuffer, so that the window appears on a virtual screen instead of your real screen.

This also allows to easily run your tests on a headless machine, such as a build server.

On Linux, we're using `xvfb` for this particular purpose. More info: [How To Run Your Tests Headlessly with Xvfb](http://elementalselenium.com/tips/38-headless)

For Windows, see [Is there anything like xvfb or xnest for Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/944086/is-there-anything-like-xvfb-or-xnest-for-windows)

Comment: Thanks for your answers, Kos and @lauda. I was hoping there would be a simple solution, but I don't feel like installing a new soft in order to achieve this. I'll just have a cup of coffee while running my tests...

Comment: @Roubi a simple solution is work in progress: https://twitter.com/samccone/status/739166801427210240

Answer (score 0):

Seems there is no method for launching in background. `maximizeWindow` is for setting the resolution.

You should try to run in a virtual machine or on another PC in order to avoid this kind of issues, popups and interacting by mistake with the window that runs automation.

Running on the same machine should be done when writing new tests and when debugging.

Answer (score 0):

I found an acceptable solution for this that didn't require me to run Chrome headless or in a virtual machine.

Simply log in with a secondary user account on your local machine, and run selenium on that account. Then, switch back to your main user account and run your tests. The chrome browser will be created under the user running selenium and you will never see the chrome windows pop up.